# CMake using conda can't find include directory

Tags: c++, cmake, anaconda

I am trying to use CMake to compile a C++ program. I am using CMake installed with Anaconda (specifically miniconda3). When compiling, Anaconda isn't able to find headers contained in `/usr/include/`

My main CPP file looks like this:

```cpp
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "dna.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Version " << DNA_VERSION_MAJOR << "." << DNA_VERSION_MINOR << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Specifically, I am trying to access the header called `GL/gl.h` which is found at `/usr/include/GL/gl.h`

My `CMakeList.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(DNA VERSION 1.0)
# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
configure_file(dna.h.in dna.h)
include_directories("/usr/include/")
add_executable(dna-viz main.cpp dna.h)
target_include_directories(
        dna-viz PUBLIC 
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
        "${CONDA_PREFIX}/include"
    )
```

My error when running `mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..` is as follows:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/debesh/general/dna-vis/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/debesh/general/dna-vis/build'
Scanning dependencies of target dna-viz
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/debesh/general/dna-vis/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/debesh/general/dna-vis/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dna-viz.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/debesh/general/dna-vis/build/dna.h:4:0,
                 from /home/debesh/general/dna-vis/main.cpp:6:
/home/debesh/miniconda3/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:210:12: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
   #include <GL/gl.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dna-viz.dir/build.make:80: CMakeFiles/dna-viz.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/debesh/general/dna-vis/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:93: CMakeFiles/dna-viz.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/debesh/general/dna-vis/build'
make: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2
```

Is this because `GL/gl.h` and `GLFW/glfw3.h` are installed in different places?

I have installed a load of different `xorg-*` and also `mesagl` packages using `conda install` but this still isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those errors are telling you that you are missing a library.

`fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory #include <GL/gl.h>`
You need to install `mesalib`.

For `Gl/gl.h` on Linux use:

or `sudo apt install mesa-common-dev`

or use `conda install mesalib`

Comment: using linux and tbh it is easy to install using apt-get but conda compilers weren't finding it - I think there might be a different solution for packages not available on anaconda - in the end i just didnt realise that there was a conda package!